# Hibernate fails to delete an item from a list of entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that contains a `List<Application> applications` which is persisted in a database. I would like to delete a specific `Application` object from the database, including all of its references, i.e. entries in the mapping table (`JoinTable`) with a foreign key to the `Application`.

While I can successfully delete a database row from the `JoinTable` mapping table, I can't get `EntityManager` to delete the actual `Application` row - the row either stays in the database even after calling `entityManager.remove()`, or all tables in the database are wiped clean, or an exception occurs.

The entities are (details omitted for clarity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "virtual_machine")
public class VirtualMachine extends ExternalObject
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "virtual_machine_has_applications", inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>(0);
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "application")
public class Application extends Common
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private VirtualMachine vm;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "myapp")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyApp extends Application
{
    @Column(name = "myapp_name")
    private String name;
}
```

Now, **I want to delete a specific `MyApp` from the `application` table, as well as the mapping row in the `virtual_machine_has_applications`**. This is all happening wihtin a transaction. First, I search for the application to delete:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < virtualMachine.getApplications().size(); i++)
{
    // Find Application to be deleted. virtualMachine is retrieved from within the same scope/transaction.
    Application app = virtualMachine.getApplications().get(i);                  
    if (app instanceof MyApp && someCriterion)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

// Attempt to delete the application from the DB:
virtualMachine.getApplications().remove(index);
entityManager.merge(virtualMachine);
```

This only deletes the row inside the `virtual_machine_has_applications`, but the record still persists in the `application` table. How can I also delete the record from the latter correctly?

Here's what I tried, with no success:

```
Application app = virtualMachine.getApplications().remove(index);
entityManager.merge(virtualMachine);
entityManager.remove(app);
```

and

```
MyApp myApp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < virtualMachine.getApplications().size(); i++)
{
    ...         
    if (app instanceof MyApp && someCriterion)
    {
        index = i;
        myApp = (MyApp) app;
        break;
    }
}

virtualMachine.getApplications().remove(index);
entityManager.merge(virtualMachine);
entityManager.remove(myApp);
```

Both these attempts result in `javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query` exception, and the entire database is wiped afterwards.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Calling only `entityManager.remove(myApp);` without other lines passes without an exception, but for some reason pretty much every table in the database is wiped completely afterwards (no records remain in `application` anymore).

Comment: you have marked both entities for `CascadeType.ALL` , which means , that either if you are going to delete `Application ` it will clear the `VirtualMachine` or the same if you are going to clear the `VirtualMachine ` it will try to clear all the `Application` s that are being referred. To double check , open the Show_Sql flag

Comment: Did you try just em.remove(myApp); without removing it from a collection?

Comment: @Stan I tried that - no exception occurs, but all the tables of the entities are wiped clean - in fact, most of the database remains empty after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
Application app = virtualMachine.getApplications().remove(index);                      
entityManager.merge(virtualMachine);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.createQuery("delete from Application where uuid=:id").setParameter("id", app.getId()).executeUpdate();
```

I don't know why using `entityManager.remove()` doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `orphanRemoval = true` ?